# Movies & TV Self-Evaluation: How ARE You Doing?

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

There are lots of metrics we can use to "measure" a site, and we do, but none of them matter as much as having a healthy and happy site full of interesting questions and expert answers.

So, let's talk about site health. Specifically, *your* site health.

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from Movies & TV. Review them and take a look around the Internet as if you were trying to find answers to them. Are they interesting questions? Are the answers we have better than what Google has to offer? Are they easily found?

Upvote the corresponding post in this "thread" when our answer is better. Downvote when Google wins. If we're kinda on par with Google, just use common sense and your expertise to guide your vote. :)

Comment to let us know your thoughts... and if you need help, use our [handy dandy guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQxi7.png).

Note: This evaluation will close on **11 May 2012!**

Comment: I've added my votes, hopefully enough people see this to get a decent turnout.

Comment: Added my votes.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, everyone! I'll post results and feedback later on. :)

Answer (score 7):

[Why cutting an 'X' into ammunition?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/why-cutting-an-x-into-ammunition)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Searching for "why x in ammunition" results in first Google result.  Answer is well written but could use a *slight* (very tiny) format clean up.  My analysis: **Better**

Answer (score 6):

[Why all the profanity in Deadwood?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/why-all-the-profanity-in-deadwood)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Searching for question title results in first Google result.  Answer is basically quotes with no user input, but properly sourced.  My analysis: **Better**

Answer (score 5):

[English puns in OSS 117, Cairo Nest of Spies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/english-puns-in-oss-117-cairo-nest-of-spies)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Searching for "english puns from french" resulted in 6th Google result.  Answers range from well worded answer with no sources to a slight rant with some reasoning.  My analysis: **Par**

Comment: I up-voted this one as I feel it is slightly better than par.

Answer (score 4):

[Reference for 'headlight eyes' in Cars 2?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1497/reference-for-headlight-eyes-in-cars-2)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Searching for "cars 2 headlight eyes" results in 5th search result.  Answer cites no sources but makes well reasoned guess with a proper formatting. My analysis: **Better**

Answer (score 4):

[What is the name of the John Woo movie that has this telephone caller id tracing battle scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1480/what-is-the-name-of-the-john-woo-movie-that-has-this-telephone-caller-id-tracing)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Searching for "john woo telephone trace" Resulted in top result.  Answer provides proper reasoning for identify guess with a source and reasoning right in the answer.  My analysis: **Better**

Answer (score 3):

[Does George Lucas have a plan for how The Clone Wars series will continue into the movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/does-george-lucas-have-a-plan-for-how-the-clone-wars-series-will-continue-into-t)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Searching for "clone wars tv plan" resulted in 8th Google result.  Answer is concise and answers question perfectly.  My analysis:  **Par**

Answer (score 2):

[What is the name of this Vietnam War-related movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/what-is-the-name-of-this-vietnam-war-related-movie)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Searching for "80s vietnam walk on tracks" (a bit convoluted search term) resulted in 3rd result. (previous attempts with quote in question did not even result in front page, did not check beyond that).  There is no accepted answer but several ranging from one liners to well thought out answers with sources.  Going against the chart, My analysis: **Par**

Answer (score 2):

[First Hollywood (or at least made in USA) movie where Russian dialog was spoken by Russian speaking actor?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1423/first-hollywood-or-at-least-made-in-usa-movie-where-russian-dialog-was-spoken)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Searching for "first usa made russian movie" (awkward term, no other tried before this), returned 5th result.  The question has one well written answer that alludes to there might not be an answer to this question with a well written explanation.   My analysis: **Better**

Answer (score -2):

[Silent film created after 1990](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1494/silent-film-created-after-1990)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Question had a weird genesis from list question to occurrence question.  Google search for "silent film since 1990" results in 3rd result.  Answers are one liners or lists, and not very wordy.  My analysis: **Worse/Par**

Answer (score -2):

[What is the significance of a man sitting on the train engine in the last scene of "Live and Let Die"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/what-is-the-significance-of-a-man-sitting-on-the-train-engine-in-the-last-scene)

Better than, worse than, or similar to other sites out there?

Comment: Searching for "live and let die samedi immortal" results in 4th Google result.  Top answer summarizes well various sources in a concise manner.  Other answers do not cite a source, but provide proper reasoning.  Because this does not have an accepted answer; My analysis: **Par**